# My male cat led me into the woods and onto a dirt mound

Tags: cats, behavior

my cat that we had for 1+ years started to meow at me today (which he barely does) he's a outdoor cat and visits for a few hours of the day and goes off somewhere else he started to meow a lot and walked some steps down our driveway (which is connected to a road) and turned back to see if I was still there and then continued walking, he crossed our road into the woods (still making sure I followed him) and he stopped at a dirt mound (or maybe a really old log) and stayed there meowing at me he kept biting at my sleeve the hem of my shirt and the hood of my sweater I tried sweeping the leaf's around the mound and found a mud flap from a car, I had to leave cause it was cold out but meowed and ended up following me until he went back into the woods, anyone know why he was so insistent on being there?

Comment: Please update us when you dig the mound.

Answer (score 3):

Bones in the woods or something else that’s wrong/right with the area?

Maybe you should dig?

Dirt mound could be a shallow grave and your cat is smelling the decomposition, and I know you’ve probably thought that.  Sure it may sound like you’re at the beginning of a detective novel, but they do get inspiration from true events once in a while.

Or it could be a that your cat thinks you could use the mud flap.

Either way, dig, and tell us what you find.

Comment: Agree, given that cats are solitary hunters, the fact that your cat actually alerted you to something and went through the effort of leading you there warrants further investigation. In contrast to pack animals, cats generally deal with interesting finds on their own, but in this case yours seems convinced this one requires your attention.

Comment: Related to detective novels, be sure to let your family know where you're going, and bring a camera so everyone at the bar can enjoy the story afterwards!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way we can answer this conclusively.

Keep in mind that cats have a sense of smell almost as good as dogs.  The only reason we don't have bomb sniffing police cats is that cats are harder to train because of the lack of alpha in their hierarchy. Still, there was at least [one "caviar sniffing police cat" in Russia  which were killed by the smugglers](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2003/jul/14/russia.nickpatonwalsh).

Back to your question, he might have *smelled or heard* something in the mound.

Alternatively, he might have sensed something around the mound, which might have triggered some meaningless connection in his memory. For example, we know that stray dogs bark at some people with no reason and don't bark at others, again with no reason. The generally accepted theory is that they are making a connection between their current observations and their experiences. If a dog was attacked by a man with a blue plastic bag,  he might bark at all man, or anyone who wears blue or anyone who carries a plastic bag. I believe there is no reason this behaviour wouldn't extend to cats as well. In other words, it is not possible to divulge much information only from what you describe.

But your cat continuing to act weird near the mound makes me believe whatever triggered your cat was still there.

I hope this helps.